# Наследование php

Tags: наследование, php, ооп

Есть класс:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

}
```

и наследующий класс:

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{
   public  $isLogged = false;
}
```

В конечном классе:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
var_dump($this->isLogged);
```

}
    }

нет доступа к переменной: var_dump($this->isLogged);

Пишет:

```
Message: Undefined property: Home::$isLogged
```

Answer (score 4):

Опишу подробнее на примере:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $propertyOfMY_Controller;
    public methodOfMy_Controller() {}    
}

class Auth extends MY_Controller{
    public $propertyOfMY_Controller; // Унаследовано от родителя
    public methodOfMy_Controller() {} // Унаследовано от родителя    
    public  $isLogged = false; // Свойство производного класса, отсутсвует
        // My_Controller
}

class Home extends MY_Controller {
    public $propertyOfMY_Controller; // Унаследовано от MY_Controller
    public methodOfMy_Controller() {} // Унаследовано от MY_Controller    
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump($this->isLogged); // Ошибка: isLogged отсутствует у Home и у   My_Controller
    } 
}
```

Правильное наследование:

```
 class Home extends Auth {
    public $propertyOfMY_Controller; // Унаследовано от MY_Controller
    public methodOfMy_Controller() {} // Унаследовано от MY_Controller
    public isLogged = false; // Унаследовано от Auth
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump($this->isLogged); // Теперь isLogged доступен из Home
    } 
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое - смысл понял

Answer (score 3):

вы наследуете класс Home от MY_Controller, а в MY_Controller нету свойства isLogged

Напишите class Home extends Auth и тогда все заработает

Comment: да - но ведь Auth extends MY_Controller расширяет класс MY_Controller, следовательно  Home extends MY_Controller  - должен иметь доступ?

Comment: суть в том, что я во всех классах должен использовать extends MY_Controller, потому как MY_Controller - у меня базовый класс, который я хочу расширять другими классами

Comment: Ну так, если вы наследуете класс Home от класса Auth, то он одновременно наследует и свойства и методы My_Controller, так как Auth производный класс от My_Controller

Comment: @IOleg,

> да - но ведь Auth extends MY_Controller расширяет класс MY_Controller, следовательно Home extends MY_Controller - должен иметь доступ?

не будет иметь доступа. в вашем примере классы Auth и Home независимы друг от друга

> суть в том, что я во всех классах должен использовать extends MY_Controller, потому как MY_Controller - у меня базовый класс, который я хочу расширять другими классами

можна сделать так: либо $this->isLogged поместить в MY_Controller либо в классе Auth определить статический метод, который возвращает isLogged и тогда обращаться к нему так - Auth::isLogged();

Comment: А если в этих классах есть одинаковая переменная public $data = array(), который заполняется этими классами, но на выходе в class Home получаю кашу, как правильно организовать?

Comment: Одинаковая в том смысле, что она у вас объявляется и в базовом и в производном классе? Или просто наследуется из базового?

Comment: i tam i tam obiyavlena

Comment: Попробуйте почитать в документации или литературе про такие ключевые слова, как parent и self, и оператор расширения области видимости ::, я думаю это поможет вам глубже понять принципы обращения к родительским свойствам и методам